# Drag and drop more than one sprite (image) on Libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

well i am trying to achieve the same effect of windows desktop , you can select multiple icons and drag all of them to differents positions.

here you can see how i select the images
[image: here you can see how i select the images]

[image: in the second image you can see the three sprites selected]

in the second image you can see the three sprites selected.

my problem is the only one of the images are moving! not the three :/

here is my code:

```
public class Nivel extends GameState implements InputProcessor {

    private Texture tex;
    private Sprite sprite;
    private Array<Sprite> sprites;

    private boolean isdragged = false;

    private float x1 = 0;
    private float y1 = 0;
    private float x2 = 0;
    private float y2 = 0;
    private Rectangle rec;
    private Array<Sprite> seleccionados;
    private Vector3 vector = new Vector3();
    private boolean selected = false;
    private TextureRegion region;

    public Nivel(GameStateManager gsm) {
        super(gsm);
        tex = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("badlogic.jpg"));
        tex.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);
        sprites = new Array<Sprite>();
        seleccionados = new Array<Sprite>();//sprites inside the rectangles
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            sprite = new Sprite(tex);
            sprites.add(sprite);
        }
        rec = new Rectangle(-100, -100, 0, 0);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleInput() {}

    @Override
    public void update(float dt) {
        for (int i = 0; i < sprites.size; i++) {
            sprites.get(i).setOrigin(sprite.getWidth() / 2, sprite.getHeight() / 2);
            if (rec.contains(sprites.get(i)
                    .getBoundingRectangle()) && !isdragged)//check if rectangle collide with sprites and select them
            {
                sprites.get(i).setColor(Color.GREEN);
                seleccionados.add(sprites.get(i));
                selected = true;
            }
        }

        if (!isdragged) {
            rec.set(-100, -100, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        sb.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

        sb.begin();
        for (int i = 0; i < sprites.size; i++) {
            if (seleccionados.contains(sprites.get(i), true))
                continue;
            sprites.get(i).setBounds(i * 110, 100, 100, 100);
            sprites.get(i).draw(sb);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < seleccionados.size; i++) {//array of sprite that has been selected

            if (!isdragged)
                seleccionados.get(i).setBounds(seleccionados.get(i).getX(), seleccionados.get(i).getY(), 100, 100);
            else
                seleccionados.get(i).setBounds(x2 - seleccionados.get(i).getWidth() / 2, y2 - seleccionados.get(i)
                        .getHeight() / 2, 100, 100);//move the selected sprites , only work for one :c

            seleccionados.get(i).draw(sb);
        }
        sb.end();


        renderer.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        renderer.begin(ShapeType.Line);
        renderer.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        if (isdragged && !selected) {
            float px = Math.min(x1, x2);
            float py = Math.min(y1, y2);
            float pw = Math.abs(x1 - x2);
            float ph = Math.abs(y1 - y2);

            rec.set(px, py, pw, ph);
            renderer.rect(px, py, pw, ph);
        }
        renderer.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        tex.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        Vector3 vector = new Vector3(screenX, screenY, 0);
        vector = camera.unproject(vector);
        x1 = vector.x;
        y1 = vector.y;
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        isdragged = false;

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
        Vector3 vector = new Vector3(screenX, screenY, 0);
        vector = camera.unproject(vector);
        x2 = vector.x;
        y2 = vector.y;
        isdragged = true;

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you assign each selected Sprite the same coordinates and they end up being drawn on top of each other:

```
seleccionados.get(i).setBounds(x2 - seleccionados.get(i).getWidth() / 2, y2 - seleccionados.get(i)
                    .getHeight() / 2, 100, 100);
```

Each sprite in `seleccionados` has the same width and height, so `x2 - seleccionados.get(i).getWidth()` always evaluates to the same number.

Also, here are multiple suspicious things / tips I noticed in this code:

- While you add to `seleccionados` on every frame, you never clear it, so each frame will be a little slower until the game crashes as it runs out of memory
- You don't have to do `seleccionados.get(i).setBounds(seleccionados.get(i).getX(), seleccionados.get(i).getY(), 100, 100);`, Sprite has `setSize(float, float)` method which does the same. But do you really need to set the size on each frame?
- Using `for (Sprite selected : seleccionados)` (for-each loop) instead of `for (int i = 0; i < seleccionados.size; i++)` will make the code more readable